# Navigation bar positioning

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am making a website and my navigation bar's drop down is not lining up with the parent navigation bar when I try and position it into the middle of the page. When I use relative positioning, it does not line up. This is my code:

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #A7C5A5;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0em;
  color: #030;
  background-color: #A7C5A5;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  top: 60px;
  left: 300px;
  float: inherit;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
  background-color: #A7C5A5;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 300px;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bg-right"></div>
  <div id="bg-left"></div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="greenlogo.jpg" width="504" height="160">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Animals</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Disney</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Farm</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nickolodean</a>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a fiddle for private and I saw in Chrome-Devconsole that some styles are double used or used where you won't that they are used. I would recommend to use classes for the different ul's

Devlen